# Azure App Service Runtime Stack Availability in portal.azure.com

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

We are running several Azure App Services with different Runtime stacks.

- Recently we were waiting for Asp. Net 4.8 to be officialy available as Runtime stack and we needed to plan when we could upgrade our application without performing any workarounds. At a time we were able to find article like [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/app-service-net-framework-48-support-now-available/), but it was not predictable.
- Right now we are discussing when should we upgrade our PHP 7.2 application to PHP 7.4 because PHP 7.2 will no longer be available. Therefore we need to find out when this change happens?

**Could you please advise reliable source where we can check what is the plan regarding adding new options to Runtime stack of Azure App Service and removing the old ones?**

I mean for all technologies: .Net, PHP, Java, Node, .. The ideal format of such source would be similar to [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)

Comment: Just a note for PHP 7.4: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/community-support-for-php-74-is-ending-on-28-november-2022/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [Azure Services Updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/?) to get the updates on the products and services you like.

For more details on [PHP on App Service](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/php_support.md#end-of-life-for-php-74)

Here is the detailed version list and its support timelines.

[image]